# How to pass comma separated multi select values to the url on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have a basic GET form in my project that is used to filter through posts created by users. When I submit the form the values from the multiple select input are appended to the url like so:

```
project.dev/?maps[]=1&maps[]=2&maps[]=3
```

As you can see, the values are passed to the url via three separate key value pairs... However, I would like to know how to append the values to the url in the following format:

```
project.dev/?maps=1,2,3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you show the form but with the current setup, on the server side, you should end up with `$_GET['maps'] = [1,2,3]`  is there some reason you dont want to just access the variables like `$_GET['maps'][1]`?

Comment: @DelightedD0D My question is more of an attempt to shorten the URL and remove the unnecessary key value pairs, functionally it works fine. The form is just a basic GET form with a couple of  single select inputs and one multiple select input (http://pastebin.com/3EKCF6Bb).

Comment: For what reason do you want to shorten the URL? You could just use the POST method on your form which would remove the params from the URL completely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to this and thought I'd share it in hopes to help others overcome the same problem in the future.

**HTML**

```
<select id="region" name="region" multiple>
    <option value="1">Region 1</option>
    <option value="2">Region 2</option>
    <option value="3">Region 3</option>
</select>

<select id="maps" name="maps[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">Map 1</option>
    <option value="2">Map 2</option>
    <option value="3">Map 3</option>
</select>

<button id="search">Search</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#search").click(function() {
            var params = {};
            var getSelect = ['region', 'maps'];

            $.each(getSelect, function(index, value) {                  
                var select = $('#' + value);

                if (select.val() != '') {
                    var selected = select.val();

                    if (select.attr('multiple'))
                        selected = selected.join(',');

                    params[value] = selected;
                }
            });

            if (!$.isEmptyObject(params)) {
                var url = [location.protocol, '//', location.host, location.pathname].join('');

                window.location.href = url + '?' + $.param(params);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to send an array, how about Array.prototype.join?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

console.log(arr.join(','));

// result: 1,2,3
```

Comment: While this may in fact be part of the solution, it doesnt actually address the question which has more to do with how the OP submits the data than simply joining the values

Comment: @user3191461 Thank you for the reply, this helped me solve the problem. +rep